# If $A\geq B$ and $B$ has rank at most $n$, then why $\lambda_{n+1}(A)\geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B$ be $m\times m$ matrices with $A\geq B$, and suppose that $B$ has rank at most $n$. Then, why is the $(n+1)$-th smallest eigenvalue of $A$, $\lambda_{n+1}(A)$, is not smaller than 0?

This assertion comes in Barry Simon's paper "Semiclassical analysis of lowlying eigenvalues. I.
Non-degenerate minima : asymptotic expansions", proof of theorem 3.2.

The relevant part of the paper is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if it is a well known fact, but how do you define a relation order in the set of matrices? I guess you have to clarify what you mean by $A\geq B$.

Comment: @Marcos It is defined in a standard way: $A\geq B$ iff $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: The result follows from two facts: (1) $\lambda_{n+1}(B)\ge0$ (because the rank of $B$ is at most $n$); (2) $\lambda_i(A)\ge\lambda_i(B)$ for each $i$ (because $A\ge B$).

Comment: @user1551 Thanks a lot! I think this should be an answer, not comment.